# Is there a shorter way to fill a Set with a default item if was empty

Tags: scala, collections, functional-programming, scala-collections

Suppose a `cars` list.

I want to add the `Ferrari` item **only if** the **Set** is **empty**, and return the final Set.

I do this:

```
val finalCarsSet = Option(cars) filterNot(_.isEmpty) getOrElse Set("Ferrari")
```

Is there a shorter way using higher-order functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you wrap the list in an option? You could use `isEmpty`:

```
scala> Set()
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Nothing] = Set()

scala> if(res0.isEmpty) Set("Ferrari") else res0
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[_ <: String] = Set(Ferrari)

scala> Set("Ferrari", "Porsche")
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(Ferrari, Porsche)

scala> if(res2.isEmpty) Set("Ferrari") else res2
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(Ferrari, Porsche)
```

One thing I don't understand form your code is if you want to return a set only with "Ferrari" or you want to add the car to the set you already have.

Comment: But I tried to avoid conditionals. Of course with conditional I can. If there's no shorter way than conditional, I would use it ;)  For your last sentence => `Set` is immutable in my case.

Comment: Well to be honest here conditional make your code shorter, and I would argue more legible than wrapping the list into another type and having to use `filter` and `getOrElse`.

Comment: I agree with you, but I wondered if there is an amazing way of doing this that I might ignore ;)

Comment: Not that I can think of, probably somebody has a better alternative :)

Comment: I really think you're right. I can only valid your answer in 5 minutes (stackoverflow constraint) :) Will do it. Thanks